# How to compare char with a char linked list value?

Tags: c, linked-list, char, compare, strcmp

So basically I have a linked list node that has a char variable called missed that takes in a single char earlier on in my program. I am just trying to compare that char to a hardwritten char 'a','b','c' or 'd' in order to increment a counter.Running the program is giving me an Access Violation.

```
if (strcmp(&temp->missed, 'a') == 0) {
noTackle++;
}
```

I am comfortable with Java but new to C so is this an issue with how I am comparing or how I am calling my node or have I got it all horribly wrong?Any help appreciated

Comment: What exactly are *handwritten* chars?

Comment: Sorry I meant hardcoded,fixed values

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` is used to compare strings; you are trying to compare individual characters here, which can be done with just `==`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to (read: can't) use `strcmp()` to compare single characters. Assuming `temp->missed` is a `char` then all you need is `if (&temp->missed == 'a') { ...`

You can also possibly simplify: `if (temp.missed == 'a') { ...`